# Twitter4j: Cannot use StatusListener cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, twitter, twitter4j

I'm struggling with Twitter4j. I am using a Maven project with the following Twitter4j dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>[4.0,)</version>
</dependency>
```

However every time I try and declare a StatusListener, I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'StatusListener'` even though I'm importing `import twitter4j.*;`.

Anyone know why this might happen when I can use pretty much all other features of Twitter4j?

Comment: What version of twitter4j lib shows up in maven dependency tree?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>[4.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
```

As a dependency to my pom.xml. Turns out the Streaming API and all related classes are in a different part of the Twitter4J ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

As twitter4j lib contains the core, async, example, and a stream part. You should try to include all these but mainly the stream dependency contains the status listener method. I hope it solves your problem.